# On cofibrations of simplicially enriched categories

Tags: higher-category-theory, model-categories, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be an strict 2-category and denote by $C$ is underlying 1-category viewed as as a 2-category only having identity 2-cells.

We have a canonical inclusion functor ,

$$i: C \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}.$$

The usual nerve functor,

$$N: \mathsf{Cat} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}_{\Delta},$$
preserves limits therefore it induces another functor,

$$N_{2}: 2\text{-}\mathsf{Cat}  \longrightarrow \mathsf{Cat}_{\Delta}$$
obtained by applying nerve to each Hom-category, where $\mathsf{Cat}_{\Delta}$ is the category of simplicially enriched categories.

Let us consider $\mathsf{Cat}_{\Delta}$ endowed with the Joyal-enriched model structure. I would like to know if then  $N(i)$ would be a cofibration of simplicially enriched categories.

If this is not true in general I would be very interested in knowing if there are some conditions on $\mathbb{C}$ that ensure that the induced map will be a cofibration.

Comment: The short answer is "its (really) not often a cofibration". Cofibration of simplicial categories are maps obtained by freely adding simplex (relative simplicial computades). Nerves of 2-categories will almost nerve be of this form. Though it might possible to give a more precise answer to your question.